# Is it possible to add value constraints for string property via Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constraints

I'm implementing user's language setting to store it in database:

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public CultureInfo Culture => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Language) ? Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture : new CultureInfo(Language);
}
```

Is it possible to specify `Language` values can be? For example: *"sl-SI"* or *"hr-HR"* or *"ru-RU"* only?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can create an enum of supported languages and use helper for strings:

```
public enum SupportedLanguages
{
    [Description("sl-SL")]
    Sl,
    [Description("hr-HR")]
    Hr,
    [Description("ru-RU")]
    Ru
}

public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{            
    FieldInfo field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    DescriptionAttribute attribute
            = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute))
                as DescriptionAttribute;

    return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
}
```

Then use this like this

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private SupportedLanguages language;
    public SupportedLanguages Language 
    { 
        get { return language; }
        set 
        {
            if(!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(SupportedLanguages), value))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            language = value;
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public CultureInfo Culture => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Language.GetDescription()) ? Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture : new CultureInfo(Language.GetDescription());
}
```

Comment: What about `ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into Users(Language) values (22)")` and `user.Language = (SupportedLanguages)22`?

Comment: Are you sure, you can try it by yourself

Comment: You can't assign an invalid integer value to a enum field. The whole idea behind enum is this. Also you can invalidate database in many ways manually but if you use EF all the way you don't need to worry about it

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Sure I forgot that in C# enums are not checked! and it's for Flags capability. I have edited the answer see the new one.

Comment: Improving my code I think it would be better to make `SupportedLanguages` property required and remove extra validation from `get` method of `Culture` property.

Comment: Also the problem is you store `data` in `Description` attribute. As I can understand this attribute isn't for containing any data. Probably the best solution is to create a new table in DB with supported languages.

Comment: The description is a normal string just like the ones you use to fill. I also think it's good approach to store in db for scalability but it's unnecessary complecation for your question

Comment: I mean that "ru-RU",... is not description. This is data we are passing to `CultureInfo` constructor. Of course we can use it but I think it was implemented for another cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it at migration:

```
public override void Up()
{  
    Sql("ALTER TABLE Users ADD CONSTRAINT LanguageCnst CHECK (Language in ('sl-SI', 'hr-HR', 'ru-RU'))");
}

public override void Down()
{
    Sql('ALTER TABLE Users DROP CONSTRAINT LanguageCnst');
}
```

And add some code to `User`:

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; protected set; }

    public setLanguage(string value)
    {
        if(new[]{"sl-SI", "hr-HR", "ru-RU"}.Contains(value))
            Language = value;
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public CultureInfo Culture => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Language) ? Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture : new CultureInfo(Language);
}
```